# JMS Queue client onMessage() not receiving message from sender

Tags: jms, weblogic

I am new to JMS and working with Jdeveloper and Weblogic 12c,  My code is running well but the Consumer `onMessage()` method is not receiving any message from Producer. Though I can get a message when I didn't use the `onMessage()`. Do I have to configure any file before it work?

Here is the message consumer code

```
package com.soap_jms;



import javax.jms.ExceptionListener;
import java.util.*;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.Context;

import utils.system;


public class QueueConsume  implements MessageListener, ExceptionListener{

        private final static String JMS_FACTORY="jms/ThesisConnectionFactory";
        private final static String QUEUE="jms/ThesisJMSQueue"; 
        private static Connection mConnection;
        private static ConnectionFactory mConnectionFactory;
        private static Queue mQueue;
        private static MessageConsumer mConsumer;
        private static Session mSession;


       public static void main (String [] args) throws JMSException, NamingException {
       mConnection=null;
       MessageListener listener = null;
       System.out.println("Entering into JMS Queue Consumer........");
       Context ctx = QueueConsume.getInitialContext();
       mConnectionFactory=(javax.jms.ConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
       mQueue=(javax.jms.Queue)ctx.lookup(QUEUE);
       mConnection=mConnectionFactory.createConnection();
       mSession=mConnection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
       mConsumer=mSession.createConsumer(mQueue);
       QueueConsume mConsume = new QueueConsume();
       mConsumer.setMessageListener(mConsume);
       mConnection.setExceptionListener(mConsume);
       mConnection.start();

       System.out.println("JMS is set to accept sent message.....");
       System.out.println("Exiting from JMS Queue Consumer ........"); 
       close();
       } // closes main method


    @SuppressWarnings("oracle.jdeveloper.java.insufficient-catch-block")
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Message is " + ((TextMessage) message).getText());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
        }
    }
      @SuppressWarnings("oracle.jdeveloper.java.unchecked-conversion-or-cast")
    public static Context getInitialContext() throws JMSException, NamingException {
            Hashtable htb = new Hashtable();
            htb.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
            htb.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://localhost:7101");
            Context ctx= new InitialContext(htb);
        return ctx;   
        }       


    public static void close() throws JMSException {
        mSession.close();
        mConnection.close();
        mConsumer.close();
    }



    public void onException(JMSException exception)
        {
          System.err.println("an error occurred: " + exception);
        } 

}
```

Comment: Have you attached the onMessage message listener to consumer?

Comment: Yes Shashi. I attached it. see the code above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is because the main thread is ending before the  `onMessage` method is called. After `Connection.start()` method is called you are calling `close`. Typically the setMessageListener is an asynchronous operation, so the call returns immediately but actual starting of `onMessage` thread happens in parallel. Suggest you to put some sleep  or some other way to make the main thread to wait while `onMessage` thread receives messages.